# jQuery: How to create function when value of text input is changed in any way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I trying create a function on when value of text input is changes, function is working ok if i change value with manually input, but function didn't  if value  is change automatic with event on other element 
eg- if try to change value with button or range then value of text input is changed but function on text input does not work 

but i want run the function when value of text input is changed in any way

Here is codes i tryed

HTML

```
<button id="mybutton">set value to 15</button><br>
<input type="range" min="5" max="15" value="5" id="myrange" step="1" ><br>
<input id="my-input" type="text">
```

jquery

```
$('#my-input').on('keyup change', function() {
          console.log(this.value);
         });
$('#myrange').change(function(){
$('#my-input').val(this.value);
   });
$('#mybutton').click(function(){
$('#my-input').val(15);
   });
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLhhx0zL/)

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: See here http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/rLhhx0zL/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the value of range and call change handler of range not the input type text

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rLhhx0zL/4/)**

```
$('#mybutton').click(function () {
     $('#myrange').val(15).change();
});

$('#myrange').change(function () {
    $('#my-input').val(this.value).change();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually trigger the `change` event like so:

```
...
$('#my-input').val(this.value).trigger("change"); 
....
```

and

```
....
$('#my-input').val(15).trigger("change");
....
```

Entire working code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#my-input').on('keyup change', function() {
          console.log(this.value);
         });

$('#myrange').change(function(){
$('#my-input').val(this.value).trigger("change");
   });

$('#mybutton').click(function(){
$('#my-input').val(15).trigger("change");
   });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="mybutton">set value to 15</button><br>
<input type="range" min="5" max="15" value="5" id="myrange" step="1" ><br>
<input id="my-input" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

another change effect will not apply to textbox you have to manually call that function when first element change like
html

```
<input type="range" min="5" max="15" value="5" id="myrange" step="1" onchange='change(this.val);'><br>
```

Script

```
function change(val){
console.log(val);
}
```

and call like

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(){
$('#my-input').val(15);
change(15);
});
```